# Why didn't somebody at the Yorktown space station just transport Krall and the weapon into space?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

Given the threat that Krall and his represented to the Yorktown Space Station, it seems like they could have done more to kill him.

Scotty was already working with their operations people at the time so there was not a problem communicating his presence and that he was a threat.

It seems like somebody could have beamed him into a holding cell, or into outer space, or just spread his atoms around the solar system.

They also had flying police cars. Why didn't one of these just fly up to him and put a hole in his chest!

Comment: Apparently I wasn't the only person to figure this out: https://youtu.be/Fymz7yoELS4

Answer (score 3):

This is TOS era Star Trek. They still couldn't arbitrarily teleport anyone at any time, even with all the Kelvin timeline changes. They would need to know exactly where Krall was and have the skill to track him to teleport him.

We also don't know if the Yorktown, as a space station, had teleporter capabilities. There wouldn't be a pressing need, like an exploration ship would.

As to putting a hole in his chest, the United Federation of Planets just doesn't roll like that. But the lack of police support is well noted. It's excused as being plot dumb, because had there been local security involved, the plot could not continue.

Comment: As I recall, isn't there a quick shot of someone using a transport booth in the establishing crowd scene of Yorktown?

Comment: I think by the time of TOS transporters are pretty standard, and that technology would certainly be useful on a space station, e.g. to transport cargo, or people in case of an emergency. - The previous movies showed beaming onto a ship traveling at Warp speed and Khan even beamed from Earth to Klingon space.

Comment: But it still requires platforms. Site to site transporters aren't until TNG era.

Comment: They had site-to-transporter capability else nobody would be able to beam up from a planet.  Yorktown could have transported him to a pad.  I think that Krall and his device on a transporter pad inside a closed room surrounded by security guards would be better than floating around inside their air distribution system?  What they needed to introduce in movie was a transporter "blocker" or "disruptor" that Krall was wearing on his tool belt.